# Seasons by month and day

Tags: java, datetime

Write a program reads two integers representing a month and day and prints the season for that month and day. Assume that months are specified as an integer between 1 and 12 (1 for January, 2 for February, and so on) and that the day of the month is a number between 1 and 31. 
If the date falls between 12/16 and 3/15, you should print "Winter". If the date falls between 3/16 and 6/15, you should print "Spring". If the date falls between 6/16 and 9/15, you should print "Summer". And if the date falls between 9/16 and 12/15, you should print "Fall".

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int month = scan.nextInt();
    int day = scan.nextInt();

    if((month == 12 && day >= 16 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >=1 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 28) || (month == 3 && day >=1 && day <=15))
    {
        System.out.println("Winter");
    }
    else if((month == 3 && day >= 16 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >=1 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >=1 && day <=15))
    {
        System.out.println("Spring");
    }
    else if((month == 6 && day >= 16 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >=1 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >=1 && day <=15))
    {
        System.out.println("Summer");
    }
    else if((month == 9 && day >= 16 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >=1 && day <= 31) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 30) || (month == 12 && day >=1 && day <=15))
    {
        System.out.println("Fall");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And you either are missing the starting line `public class Something` or you have one too many closing `}`

Comment: Nah that's not it :/

Comment: I mean in the post, not in your code in your computer

Comment: The thing is I've sent the code in my computer to an online judge and it gave me a score of 98/100! So, there has to be something very small that is so hard to find.

Comment: We do not modify code behaviour... I mean we are happy about making the code nicer and faster, but fixing a corner case is not really on-topic... Unless the judge also counts execution time

Comment: @Caridorc Online judges normally takes code cleanliness into consideration for the score.

Answer (score 8):

**Readability**

Your conditional checks are very very long. They run off the screen. At the very least, add some new lines:

```
else if ((month == 9 && day >= 16 && day <= 30) || 
         (month == 10 && day >=1 && day <= 31) || 
         (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 30) || 
         (month == 12 && day >=1 && day <=15))
```

But this still makes it very hard to actually understand what is going on. There's no really any notion of "range" in this code. You are simply hardcoding each individual month separately.

**Ranges**

Representing the range "3/16 to 6/15" is difficult. Representing the range 316 to 615 is easy. If we don't care about checking for invalid dates, we can uniquely represent the year by doing `month * 100 + day` and looking at it that way.

```
int month_day = month * 100 + day;
if (month_day <= 315) {
    System.out.println("Winter");
}
else if (month_day <= 615) {
    System.out.println("Spring");
}
else if (month_day <= 915) {
    System.out.println("Summer");
}
else if (month_day <= 1215) {
    System.out.println("Fall");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Winter");
}
```

By treating the ranges as one-sided, it's easy to organize the code to actually look like we're looking for ranges. Winter simply appears on both ends for simplicity.

Comment: Nitpick: I wouldn't use underscores (so, `monthDay` instead of `month_day` - underscore convention is alien to Java). Clever trick anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion - encapsulated in a method to allow for calling itself:

```
void printSeason(int month, int day)
{
    switch (month)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Winter");
            break;

        case 4:
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Spring");
            break;

        case 7:
        case 8:
            System.out.println("Summer");
            break;

        case 10:
        case 11:
            System.out.println("Fall");
            break;

        // "ambiguous" months
        case 3:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 12:
            boolean firstHalf = day <= 15;
            // during first half of the month it's same season as previous month.
            // second half of the month = same season as next month.
            int adjacentMonth = month + (firstHalf ? 1 : -1);
            printSeason(adjacentMonth, day);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is how I've done it](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/blob/master/MintPlayer.SeasonChecker/SeasonChecker.cs). Although it's in C# it's just the idea that is essential. The main idea is to split the season that crosses the newyear into 2 pieces. Then you can without any problem check if your date (remapped to 2000) is within the range of one of the five season-parts.

It works every time, with every date, when checked in a leap year, and also with seasons sourced from a database.

```
public Task<TSeason> FindSeasonAsync<TSeason>(IEnumerable<TSeason> seasons, DateTime date) where TSeason : class, ISeason
{
    var result = seasons
        .Select(s =>
        {
            // Find season that crosses newyear
            if (s.Start.Year == s.End.Year)
            {
                return new[] {
                    new {
                        OriginalSeason = s,
                        // Remap the season to the year 2000
                        ProcessableSeason = new InternalSeason {
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Start = new DateTime(2000, s.Start.Month, s.Start.Day),
                            End = new DateTime(2000, s.End.Month, s.End.Day)
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                // If the season crosses the newyear, split the season
                return new[] {
                    new {
                        OriginalSeason = s,
                        // Remap the season to the year 2000
                        ProcessableSeason = new InternalSeason {
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Start = new DateTime(2000, s.Start.Month, s.Start.Day),
                            End = new DateTime(2000, 12, 31)
                        }
                    },
                    new {
                        OriginalSeason = s,
                        // Remap the season to the year 2000
                        ProcessableSeason = new InternalSeason {
                            Name = s.Name,
                            Start = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
                            End = new DateTime(2000, s.End.Month, s.End.Day)
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        })
        .SelectMany(s => s)
        .FirstOrDefault(s =>
            // Now we can easily compare the dates.
            DateTime.Compare(s.ProcessableSeason.Start, new DateTime(2000, date.Month, date.Day)) <= 0 &&
            DateTime.Compare(new DateTime(2000, date.Month, date.Day), s.ProcessableSeason.End) <= 0
        )?.OriginalSeason;

    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].